# How to use pandas Index object in custom object, in particular for slice dispatch?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, composition, multi-index

I am currently in the process of designing a new object that needs something basically identical to a `pandas.Index`, of particular interest is `MultiIndex`.

The set behaviour of pandas' Index objects is also pretty excellent, so rather than reinvent the wheel I would like to just use `pandas.Index` and its subclasses directly as our users are already familiar with `pandas`.

**Specifically, I am interested in how an Index is actually used when slicing via `loc` with particular attention to `MultiIndex`.**

I've spent a couple hours now scraping the web for any relevant information and here is what I *think* I know:

- [`pandas.Index` is intended to be subclassed.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/internals.html#indexing) In particular it looks like there is some intention of a minimal API so that `loc` dispatch works, but the docs are a little sparse here.
- Relevant source code is in [pandas/core/indexing.py](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py), but the code doesn't inspire a lot of confidence that what I want to do is easy, especially for `MultiIndex`. It isn't clear to me where the responsibility of an `Index` begins and ends.
- Use `index.slice_indexer` to resolve slices.
- Use `index.get_indexer` to resolve a subset index.

At this point it feels like I will need to handle all of the business logic for slicing myself and only defer to the index when I need to ask what the integer position of a label is, but there are still some weird things I am uncertain about:

- What does `get_value` do? I see it used extensively, but I can't seem to figure out what it's job is.
- How much can I use the `__getitem__` of an index for? It looks like it just matches `numpy` semantics. In that case would I just defer to it for boolean vectors and things like `iloc`?
- What on earth would I do to pass along a label or slice for a `MultiIndex`?